# Is there a way to get the user password using UserManager in ASP.NET Identity 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.0 and Identity 2.0. I'm trying to get the user password using UserManager. It seems there is no ways to get the password back. It gives back only the password hash. Is there a way to get the user password?

Comment: The whole point is not to be able to get the password!

Comment: Getting the password back is not a good practice at all. I am trying to migrate the old membership system to new identity. old membership system uses MembershipProvider.GetPassword to get the password. so trying to find is there a way to do the same in identity...#

Comment: I see, well...then you might want to elaborate on that question a little bit, to make it more clearer what you want to accomplish ;)

Comment: @RAM with change of the framework, you'll have to change the approach to a password reset. Identity does not allow for password retrieval, but rather does password reset link.