# How to get access on user password in ASP.Net 4.5 using identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

**Scenario**

Right now I've an project which is based on ASP.Net 4.0 using membership.

In membership I have an method named `Membership.GetUser(txtGetUsername.Text).GetPassword()` from which I can get password of specific user and this functionality is only give to admin if user faced any problems in our application he contact to admin and admin get their password and resolve his query. For security purpose we are maintaining logs.

Now I've build another application but this time I'm using ASP.Net 4.5 which is using Identity. Now I build the same page for admin to get the user password but how can I do this in Identity?

I've search on google related to my question but didn't resolve my query. I've also share some related questions with you as a reference.

[Get password from a user with UserManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290863/get-password-from-a-user-with-usermanager)

[Is there a way to get the user password using UserManager in ASP.NET Identity 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050883/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-user-password-using-usermanager-in-asp-net-identity-2?rq=1)

Comment: Doesn't the comment under your second linked question answer this? You can not, and you should not want to be able to get a user's password. Never. Also not "only for admins".

Comment: So what I do in my case? Any suggestions?

Comment: Reset the password if needed?

Comment: @oerkelens you means when Admin needs to check the user profile he simply reset the password of the specific user and later on user can change its password after issue has been resolved by admin?

Answer (score 2):

to my knowledge what you want is simply impossible to achieve with identity, at least not by its default settings.By default, Identity calculate the hash for user's password and store the hash in database. but it provides a password reset procedure in case user forget the password.

identity PasswordHash break down :

https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2017/11/29/asp-net-identity-passwordhash/